# Password protected RSS feeds in Joomla

Tags: rss, passwords, joomla2.5

I would like to generate RSS feeds from posts in Joomla 2.5 that are only available for logged in users. These feeds need to be accessed by RSS readers mainly on mobile devices.

How can I password protect them to make them accessible to the users RSS readers using the same login and password that they also use to access the news on the website?

Ideally the RSS feeds should be accessible via http authentication
(i.e. http://user:password@sitename.com/?feed=1...)

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't this be accomplished by making the RSS feed module on the relevant page, accessible to the group containing your logged in users...normally "Registered" but you could theoretically have different modules for different groups?  Not sure why you would need this...but it may provide you with a solution to your question.